# regex negative lookahead matches while it shouldn't

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Good day. I'm using the following regex to restrain users from adding "bad" stuff in a MySQL query.

```
$regex = "/\s+where(?:\s+([a-z]\w*\.?\w*)\s*=\s*(?!\1)\'?\w*\'?(?:\s*and)?)+\s*(?:order\s+by|limit|$)/uix";
```

Thing is, when trying the following query - it still matches:

```
$query = "UPDATE test set is_active = 1 where id = id ";
var_dump(preg_match($regex, $query));die;
//int(1)
```

What's even more strange, i've tried to test and debug this regex using online tools like [this](https://www.debuggex.com/),[this](https://regex101.com/r/vD2jT4/1), and regexr.com, and everywhere the regex does not match the query.
Am i missing some flag or setting or something?

edit: did not escape the \1 properly because was using double quotes. Thank you goldfish from the regex101 chat :)

Comment: Are you trying to protect against SQL Injection?

Comment: I'm trying to restrain the user from using anything but "=" in the where clause, or stuff like "id=id", which doesn't work in this case for some reason

Comment: I smell trouble...

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into prepared statements and parameterized querying. Based on your question and comment I see no reason to create such an obfuscated sanitation scheme.

Comment: It's a very long story, but in the end, all my web-service gets is the query string, and i need to perform custom checks in order to allow or deny it to execute, so it won't kill off my DB, since some of its tables have _a lot_ of data, and joining a couple of these without setting a limit will have consequences. I see two ways of doing this - either parsing the string, or using a regex. I've chosen the latter. And i don't see how prepared statements or parameterized queries can help me.

Comment: How many seconds do you think it will take a hacker to circumvent your regexp?

Comment: No idea. But if you would show me how you would bypass the restrictions in the regex and create a malicious WHERE clause, i'd be very thankful. I'm new to regexes after all, and to MySQL too, to some extent.

Comment: @ChungaChanga just google "mysql injection evasion cheat sheet" and you will be astonished how many ways there are to bypass several restrictions. I think you need to provide more info about the situation. Is the user able to craft his own queries and you need to restrict them? Also if the regex returns a match, does it mean it should be executed? or blocked? If you still insist on using a regex, you should make a clear and concise whitelist specification of what's allowed, from there on craft a regex or even several regexes to simplify the process.

Comment: So what was the before/after edit you needed for PHP?